# Can the `container` in `createPortal` just be portal-root?

Tags: reactjs

In the React portal tutorial https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html, when create a portal with `createPortal`, it created a new detached DOM node `this.el` and create portal with this element. Why do we need this step? Can we just create portal with the `modalRoot`?

Answer (score 0):

Dan explained it pretty good here:
https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/10713#issuecomment-329624968
https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/10713#issuecomment-329626097

Basically it resolved two concerns:
1. `modalRoot` could render something from the main react app. If so there would be a reconciliation issue.
2. There could be multiple modals using the same `modalRoot`. If so we need to wrap each modal in its own detached DOM nodes.

For my use case, there is only one modal rendering at any time and `modalRoot` is always empty by main react app, so it could work for me.